# Fit timestamps of multiple files/folders to existing ones

Tags: rsync, ssh-tunneling, file-copy, timestamps, synchronization

I've copied a large directory to another location (through a network). I needed to preserve all the timestamps (especially ctime  and mtime).
However somewhere in the process I screwed things up. (I probably made a typo in the flags.) And all the files have new timestamps now.
I still got the directory with the correct timestamps. But I don't want to copy it all again because it took me days. Can I somehow just sync the filestamps, e.g. with rsync?
Note that this has to be done through a ssh tunnel over a network that is rather slow. The PCs on both ends however are quite fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `rsync` is your best bet.  Something like this should work:

```
rsync -vr --size-only --times <source> <dest>
```

`--size-only` tells `rsync` not to copy the files again, `--times` tells it to update timestamps.

Comment: The "--size-only" will work but I don't think it's necessary. The regular rsync algorithm (comparing checksums) will work just fine.

Comment: @RJHunter Did you actually try it?  It will re-transfer the files, because the timestamps differ.

Comment: If rsync does "re-transfer" a file, it's usually very fast and uses little data. The rsync protocol is specifically designed to transmit only a small amount of data when both sides have similar or identical files. This is the "speedup" that rsync prints on completion. (Note that the rsync tool doesn't bother with delta-transfer when syncing local-to-local, because this is only a benefit over a network.)

Comment: @RJHunter From the OP: _I've copied a large directory to another location (through a network)._

Comment: Indeed, the OP will benefit from the speed-up of delta-transfer because of the network, as long as rsync is being used in its normal network mode. Copying from a mounted network share to a local disk would be "local-to-local" as far as rsync is concerned, so it would not benefit from the rsync protocol's delta-transfer speedup.